# How to run sourcecode compiled from C in C#

Tags: c#

I have a simple sourcecode written in C .
After compiling with GCC via command :

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

I have file hello .
I want to use C# to run the above hello file, what should I do?
I tried the following but it didn't work.

Contents of file hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

Contents in C#

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C D:\\src\\testCompileCUsingGCC\\src\\mrtbtostr\\hello";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Results after running . Error content : is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
[image]

This is the result when running the compiled hello file manually
[image: this is the result when running the compiled hello file manually]

After run command : gcc hello.c -o hello.exe
[image]

Comment: could you please be more precise about "didn't work"? because that's not an error description that is in any way useful.

Comment: The run result does not seem to be calling the compiled file hello

Comment: You are explicitly hiding the output window with `startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` so I'm not sure what output you expected? Perhaps you want to redirect the output of the process? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=net-6.0

Comment: Your question boils down to "how to start an executable" from C#. It does not really matter whether you have compiled the executable on your own from C, from Pascal or downloaded it from the some site. That part is unrelated to your question.

Comment: By reading the title, I thought you're trying to do some source code conversion.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check whether the path of hello.exe is correct
2. If you want to see the result in cmd, change
   `startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` to `startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;`

Comment: I want to hide project information so I don't put the exact path in . I have added . The run result does not seem to be calling the compiled file
 hello

Comment: try adding .exe at the end like `D:\\src\\testCompileCUsingGCC\\src\\mrtbtostr\\hello.exe`

Comment: looks like the executable build from the C program is not an exe or not built for the windows x64 or x86 platform. try to build exe (gcc hello.c -o hello.exe ) and start the process

Comment: yes, After run command : gcc hello.c -o hello.exe . 
it was able to understand the file hello.exe , but the error was:
the program can't start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of windows